# vb.net append xml item

Tags: xml, vb.net

I'm trying to append a list of "Columns" to this xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Conf>
  <name List="A">
    <columns>1</columns>
    <columns>2</columns>
    <columns>3</columns>
    <columns>4</columns>
    <columns>5</columns>
    <columns>6</columns>
  </name>
  <name List="B">
    <columns>1</columns>
    <columns>2</columns>
    <columns>3</columns>
    <columns>4</columns>
    <columns>5</columns>
    <columns>6</columns>
    <columns>9</columns>
  </name>
</Conf>
```

What I have so far:

```
 Sub NewNodeInXMLFile(ByVal strPath As String, ByVal PriceList As String, ByVal columns As List(Of String))
        Dim XMLd As New XmlDocument
        XMLd.Load(strPath)
        Dim xmlEl As XmlElement = XMLd.CreateElement("name")
        Dim xmlAttr As XmlAttribute = XMLd.CreateAttribute("List")
        xmlAttr.Value = PriceList
        xmlEl.Attributes.Append(xmlAttr)

        For Each x In columns
            xmlEl.InnerXml = "<columns></columns>"
            xmlEl.Item("columns").InnerText = x
'//what goes in here to append this item?
        Next

        XMLd.DocumentElement.AppendChild(xmlEl)
        XMLd.Save(strPath)
    End Sub
```

Basically, I know what ever goes in the for each isn't going to append the item; it's just going to write the last value of the list. Is there a way to append these items?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
For Each x In columns 
    Dim newColumn = XMLd.CreateElement("columns")
    newColumn.Value = x
    xmlEl.AppendChild(newColumn)
Next
xml.GetElementsByTagName("PriceFilesConf")[0].AppendChild(xmlEl);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Linq XElement API. Much easier to work with. But replacing your loop code with the following code should work:

```
For Each x In columns
  Dim newElement as XmlElement = XMLd.CreateElement("columns")
  newElement.InnerText = x
  xmlEl.AppendChild(newElement)
Next
```

You'll also want to change:

`XMLd.DocumentElement.AppendChild(xmlEl)`
to: `XMLd.AppendChild(xmlEl)`